# Horizontal partition in postgres-xl?

Tags: ubuntu, postgres-xl

I am using postgres-xl in ubuntu. I have a table with 9 row. I want to divide that table into 3 parts. Any idea how i do this?

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM cities;
 name | location 
------+----------
 a    |        1
 a    |        2
 a    |        4
 a    |        3
 a    |        4
 a    |        5
 a    |        6
 a    |       11
 a    |       14
(9 rows)
```

Comment: What about the condition? In which 3 parts?

Comment: @Crud3x 9 row so 9 number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. a,1 is first and a,14 is last.

Comment: You missunderstood me. Where do you want to split it into 3 parts? Like 1. {a.1,a.2,a.4} and 2. {a.3,a.4,a.5) and 3. {a.6,a.11,a.14} ??

Comment: @C4ud3x yes sir your sequence is true like that.

Comment: @C4ud3x Sir help how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it with Postgres-XL, but with the [pg_shard extension](https://www.citusdata.com/citus-products/pg-shard) you could hash-partition the table into 3 (or more) pieces:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (name text, location int);
SELECT master_create_distributed_table('cities', 'location');
SELECT master_create_worker_shards('cities', 3, 2);
```

To get started with pg_shard you can find documentation at:
https://github.com/citusdata/pg_shard

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specify your distribution strategy upon table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name VARCHAR,
    location VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (location)
)
DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(location);
```

Note that there are several pitfalls with respect to constraints, see also 
[PostgresXL CREATE TABLE documentation](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/sql-createtable.html).